# Indication for solving probability problem of a certain type

Tags: probability

Let's say that a school has 1000 computers, and that the probability of one of them breaking, in a year, is 1/5. What is the probability of at least 200 breaking in a year?

That is the problem I want to solve. The question is: how do, in general terms, go about solving it, using college level statistics?

I don't really want a full solution. I would like at least some tips and indications on what theorie/theorems I should study that would help me find a solution. I would have researched them myself, but I do not know how to search for what I want because I don't really know what I want, unfortunately. Any help would be greatly appreciated. It would save me from having to study all the topics in probability in depth, just for this one problem.

Comment: Basic familiarization with the binomial distribution should help you solve the problem

Comment: You'll need to make some assumptions.  For example, you may wish to assume that the events that each computer breaks is independent of one another.  (*this might not be a safe assumption for reality: perhaps a flood or power surge can destroy multiple at once*).  From here, you may relate the problem to a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Comment: I was indeed assuming that, but forgot to point it out. I took a quick glimpse at the Wikipedia page for the binomial distribution and it seems like what I need. I probably should have learned about it during the school year but I neglected this mathematics course and now I don't have the time to study it in enough depth and must cherry-pick the basics of everything. Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Binomial Distribution...can you turn your problem in to a coin flipping game?